# Control what red x does on window using wpf forms in c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently developing an application in c# using wpf. I would like to control what the red x (close window) does. At the moment, I press the red x and it closed the current window and continues running the rest of the program. I do not want this to happen. Instead when the x is pressed I want the whole program to finish.

Can this be done?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You want to do some event handling on the Window.Closed event, or override the Window.OnClosed method and put the code to shutdown the program in there.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.onclosed.aspx

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to DGH's answer can also be found on [codeproject's website](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42178/WPF-Close-command-on-the-Window-close-button.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to trap the closing of the form, and set a global such as "stopRequested", that other parts of the program should check while looping. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing.aspx